# missing fields of base class django serializer

Tags: django, serialization

I have few classes:

```
class Correspondent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Subject(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Letter(models.Model):
    correspondent = models.ForeignKey(Correspondent, 
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=600, blank=True)
    case_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    inventory_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    date_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class IncomingLetter(Letter):
    response_to = models.ForeignKey('OutgoingLetter', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    outgoing_number = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    incoming_number = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)


class OutgoingLetter(Letter):
    response_to = models.ForeignKey(IncomingLetter, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    outgoing_number = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
```

and in a view i trying to send json with serialized class B instances:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core import serializers
from .models import IncomingLetter
def index(request):
   ....
   some_data = IncomingLetter.objects.all()
   serialized_data = serializers.serialize('json', some_data)
   return JsonResponse(json.dumps(serialized_data), safe=False)
```

and response missed all `Letter` fields in json. Is there a way to not serialize it manually?
`serialized_data == {"model": "letters.incomingletter", "pk": 4, "fields": {"response_to": 3, "outgoing_number": "12312321", "incoming_number": "123123"}}`

## SOLVED # (not sure)

I wrote simple serializer, but not sure is this cleanest way(many unnecessary fields, but it easy to clean):

```
class LetterSerializer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.serialized_data = {}

    def serialize(self, data):
        for idx, instance in enumerate(data):
            serialized_instance_data = {}
            for key, value in instance.__dict__.items():
                serialized_instance_data[key] = str(value)
            self.serialized_data[idx] = serialized_instance_data

        return self.serialized_data
```

Comment: Can you update your question to show full imports; the serializer definition (if you're using it), the full field definitions, and other details.

Comment: @ShubhoShaha it a common django.core serializer. Edit question.

Comment: maybe i can override django core serializer?

Comment: @rtindru update.

Comment: Are `Letter`, `IncomingLetter`, and `OutgoingLetter` all concrete models or is `Letter` an abstract model?
Can you share the `serialized_data` repr in the question?

Also have you explored DRF or Tastypie? They give you comprehensive and highly configurable Serializers, and APIViews that allow you to do the same in a more structured and testable fashion.
https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: @rtindru Letter is an abstract model. I do not explored DRF and Tastypie. Added to question serialized_data repr. Thanks for links.